# Creating a dynamic 3d room in JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating an app where the user is to see how different wallpapers will look like. It is basically the inside of a 3D room of four walls where the user can drag to look around and change wallpapers from a side menu.

For the 3d room part, I looked around and found that threeJS seems like a viable option to use, but I can't seem to find any examples of this sort to build upon.

I will be happy if you can share any fiddles or repos that has the same concept.
ThreeJS seems quite old as well, is it the best option there is for such app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three.js is not at all old or outdated, it is still under active development and one of the most popular repos on github.

I would recommend looking at the [examples](https://threejs.org/examples) on threejs.org, especially the [pointer lock](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=controls#misc_controls_pointerlock) example.